# What steps are required to migrated the gocd/go-server to a new system

Tags: go-cd

I'm trying to move my gocd/go-server to a more powerful box. It's currently dockerized, but in short, i use a host volume, so i just rsync'd my whole project from system A to System B.

Composer Service Entry:

```
  go-server:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: gocd/gocd-server:v17.12.0
    ports:
      - "8153:8153"
      - "8154:8154"
    environment:
      - GO_SERVER_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES=-Dcruise.material.update.interval=10000
    volumes:
      - /opt/go/volume:/godata
      - ./password.properties:/godata/config/password.properties
```

However, when i restart the instance i get all kinds of permission errors:

```
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,756 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[PerformanceFileAppender] - openFile(/go-working-dir/logs/go-server-perf.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /go-working-dir/logs/go-server-perf.log (Permission denied)
go-server_1      |  at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /go-working-dir/logs/go-server-perf.log (Permission denied)
go-server_1      |  at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
go-server_1      |  at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
go-server_1      |  at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:26)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:204)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:127)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:100)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
go-server_1      |  at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
go-server_1      |  at  at com.thoughtworks.go.logging.LogConfigurator.configureWith(LogConfigurator.java:109)
go-server_1      |  at  at com.thoughtworks.go.logging.LogConfigurator.initialize(LogConfigurator.java:89)
go-server_1      |  at  at com.thoughtworks.go.server.util.GoLauncher.main(GoLauncher.java:41)
go-server_1      |  at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
go-server_1      |  at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
go-server_1      |  at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
go-server_1      |  at  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
go-server_1      |  at  at com.thoughtworks.gocd.Boot.run(Boot.java:104)
go-server_1      |  at  at com.thoughtworks.gocd.Boot.main(Boot.java:55)
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,756 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,757 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FileAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,757 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.thoughtworks.go] to INFO
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,757 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.thoughtworks.studios.shine] to WARN
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,757 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [ShineFileAppender] to Logger[com.thoughtworks.studios.shine]
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,757 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.thoughtworks.go.server.Rails] to WARN
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,758 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@3532ec19 - Adding [file:/go-working-dir/config/logback-include.xml] to configuration watch list.
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,763 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,763 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,764 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,766 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,766 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
go-server_1      | 22:59:53,766 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@68c4039c - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
go-server_1      |
go-server_1      | File /go-working-dir/config/cruise-config.xml is not readable or writeable.
go-server_1      | Error trying to validate file cruise-config.xsd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /go-working-dir/config/cruise-config.xsd (Permission denied)
go-server_1      | File /go-working-dir/config/jetty.xml is not readable or writeable.
go-server_1      | File /go-working-dir/config/go_update_server.pub is not readable or writeable.
go-server_1      | /go-working-dir/db/h2deltas/10_add_stage_timestamp.sql (Permission denied)
go-server_1      | /go-working-dir/db/h2db/cruise.h2.db (Permission denied)
```

I've ensured the the whole `/opt/go/volume` is owned by the logged in non-root user. IE: fred

```
$ ls -l
total 9964
-rw-r--r--. 1 fred fred 9754624 Jan  4 23:20 cruise.h2.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 fred fred  444299 Jan  4 22:11 cruise.trace.db
```

**What steps are required to migrated the gocd/go-server to a new system to bypass the permissions errors?**

Comment: The error message talks about `/go-working-dir`, but you mounted just `/godata`. Maybe try mounting both?

Comment: I think that your compose file is fine. The entrypoint script will create symlinks for /go-working-dir/ to the files in /godata that you provided to the container.
It's probably a matter of simple permissions. It is booting as user "go" so maybe try adjusting the permissions of the gocd volume files so that user go can read it, or any user even, for debugging.